# Why can't my light illuminate the room

Tags: electrical

The newly installed electric light can't be used. After changing several rooms, there is still no way. What should we do? What is the problem

Comment: What kind of light are you talking about?  Is it line voltage?  What do you mean by installed?  What is the line voltage and what are the ratings of the light?

Comment: How did the light "change several rooms"? Is it a plug in lamp and you've tried it in several outlets around the house? Is it hard-wired and you've replaced several fixtures with it? Please [edit] your post to be much more specific, and even include some picture of the electric light. (Can't imagine anyone using a gas light these days, so "electric" is a bit unnecessary, but... who knows...)

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear,  you would need to provide more details.

We don't know if the problem is with the lamp, light bulb (if there is one) or with the electricity.

As a fist diagnostic I would suggest to check:

Electricity:

- is the lamp directly connected to the mains ? or via some transformer ? or to a battery  ?
- what is the voltage (V) of your light ? (120V or 220V is mains in US or in the rest of the world)
- in what country do you live (this determines if your mains is using 120v or 220V)
- if it is on the mains, do you have electricity arriving to your plug/outlet (plug in/connect something else and see if it works ?

Bulb (if there is one):

- Try replacing it with a new bulb that has the same Voltage (V) and same or less Watts (W)

Lamp:

- Try plugging/connecting it to a different plug in a different area which you know that works.

Comment: This is a solid answer, given the vagueness of the question. Be sure to check if the OP returns to edit more detail into the question, you can also edit this answer to make sure it still applies. +1

Comment: No, sorry, but this is not a solid answer. If the question doesn't make sense as is, the answer can't make _any_ sense.